# Newtonsoft -JsonConvert : How to serialize class object key from dictionary<class,int>

Tags: c#, json.net

I have stored the class object as key and int as value in a dictionary. I want to convert the dictionary to json string,  but not getting success. I am using NewtonSoft for json convert. Here my code ,

```
 SeatInfo seatInfo = new SeatInfo() { SeatNo = 1, Status = true, NickName = "Suresh", UserID = "sss" };
Dictionary<SeatInfo, int> dic = new Dictionary<SeatInfo, int>();
dic.Add(seatInfo, 40);


string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
  {
      TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None,
      TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
  });
```

The result for this code is,

```
{"SignalRServer.SeatInfo":40}
```

How can i convert the class properties as string . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try the following code into Webservice and run Webservice:

```
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Here Copy your connection string");

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetData()
    {
        var json = "";
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> lst = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbldemo",con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> lst1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns )
            {
                lst1.Add(dc.ColumnName,row[dc]);
            }
            lst.Add(lst1);
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        json = js.Serialize(lst);
        return json;

    }
```

Comment: Hi user3824757 'JavaScriptSerializer' doesn't work for me . I m getting this error ,

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[SignalRServer.SeatInfo, SignalRServer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. But Im not sure whether this is correct or not. I just convert the dictionary object to List. So I got the class properties are as key and int as value.

```
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic.ToList(), Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
  {
      TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None,
      TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
  });
```

Here I just convert the dic object to **dic.ToList()**. The Output is ,

```
 {
    "Key": {
      "SeatNo": 1,
      "UserID": "sss",
      "NickName": "Suresh",
      "Status": true
    },
    "Value": 40
  }
```

Please guide me If I wrong, Thanks